# jQuery : zoom in web page element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Does any one know a plugin or some sample code for zoom in html element on page?
I Used *zoomooz.js* it's worked perfect but i want when user zoom in an element , the element has scroll bar.
Also my element contains another element like this :

```
<div id="zoomView">
   <div id="innerElement">
      some elements ...
      <input type="text" />
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://www.jacklmoore.com/zoom/

Comment: @baadshah I tried it before but i can't use it with my element , it's for images...

Comment: http://www.css3.com/css-zoom/

Comment: @PeterRader Thank you,Could you make a sample with it?

Comment: @samangholami sorry, this is ie only. My bad.

Comment: @Spokey I want to zoom in and the elements appear larger , also the scroll bar enabled.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript Function:

```
function zoom(value){
  document.getElementById('idofyourelement').style.zoom=value;  
}
```

in your html you can use this:

```
<!--Zoom Controls-->
<div id="zoom_controls">
  <span>-</span>
  <input type="range" min="0.7" max="2.2" value="1" step="0.1" onchange="zoom(this.value)"/>
  <span>+</span>
</div>
```

Comment: If the OP can use jQuery I would suggest moving the event to `$('#zoom-controls > input').change(function() {});` rather than inline. Remember HTML is meant for presentation not for logic!